# Connect to ch340 on MacOS Mojave

Tags: mac-os, ch340

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro to Mojave. Now I'm not able to connect to my Arduino board with ch340g usb-to-serial chip. It is a Arduino board with AtMega 328 and ESP8266 integrated. I downloaded the drivers from the Chinese website for the ch340 and also removed old installations, like some tutorials tell me. I just can't get a `/dev/cu.*` port (besides the `/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port`.

I do have an external FTDI usb to serial board. I didn't get to it to try to connect it.

Does someone know how to get the ch340 to work on MacOS Mojave, or as a last resort: use the FTDI to program/monitor the Arduino board?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this is the solution for me:

remove all old drivers:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext
sudo rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext
```

Now reboot the computer.

And then (very important, because it took me 10 cables to find the right one) use a **fully connected** cable ;-)

Now I have these ports:

```
/dev/cu.wchusbserial1410
/dev/cu.usbserial-1410
```

Comment: Sven's answer is 100% correct the `fully connected` cable is what hung me up for a few hours. Took 6 cables to find the right one.

Comment: What do you mean with "fully connected cable"? Is this a specific kind o USB cable or what?

Comment: It is a USB cable with also the data lines connected. Most cables you get with phones and devices just have the +5 and GND connected so they don't pass data.

Answer (score 1):

this my problem too.
i found these solutions

1. m[ac-usb-serial](https://www.mac-usb-serial.com/) app
2. a topic in [arduino](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=570440.0) forum

make sure delete old usb driver in these path 
/Library/Extensions/usbserial.kext  
and  
 /System/Library/Extensions/usb.kext

---

then install it again [download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lUYkw-mCOekJjY1MVA5YuEbERHNWNCZW/view)

Comment: When I experienced this problem, installing the latest driver still failed, but when I removed the old drivers and did not install anything new, it worked fine.